# Problem in using WaitForSingleObject on 64bit OS

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, 64-bit

I am using `WaitForSingleObject` from (kernel32.dll) in my program.

It is working fine on 32bit Windows XP, but when I use it on 64bit WindowsXP, it is not working.

The problem is that it doesn't wait for the process and control moves forward.

Does anyone have any idea on why?

Is there any replacement for that method in WinXP 64bit ?

Comment: Is your process running under wow64 emulation, or is it a native x64 app?  Of course this is a supported API for x64.

Comment: It is a simlple exe file and is launched as 32 bit process....

Comment: This question doesn't really have enough information to make a very educated guess.

Comment: The comment on CodeBenders answer suggests that the handle waited on is a process handle.

Answer (score 4):

If the function's return value is telling you that the process has terminated, then perhaps it really has.

Suppose the program you start comes with 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Maybe the 32-bit version can detect that it's running on a 64-bit platform, start the 64-bit version of itself, and then terminate the 32-bit version. In that case, your program would detect the termination of the 32-bit child, but it would be oblivious to the 64-bit "grandchild" process.

You can use Task Manager or Process Explorer to confirm this hypothesis. Find the program that's still running. Is its pid the same as the pid that `CreateProcess` returned to you?

Comment: I like that suggestion.  Sounds quite plausible.

Comment: The SysInternals utilities do this, they have the 32- and 64-bit executables bundled together with a custom launcher.  It's also possible that Windows itself is doing something like that with wow64...

Answer (score 3):

The `WaitForSingleObject` function is either telling you that the process is already "signaled" (`WAIT_OBJECT_0`) or an error has occurred.  To know which, we would need to know what it's returning.  If the return value is anything other than `WAIT_OBJECT_0` or `WAIT_TIMEOUT` then you need to call `GetLastError()` to determine what went wrong.

I would guess that either the process initialization failed, and you're getting `WAIT_FAILED` with `GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, or the process has already terminated and you're getting `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, but without more information we can't really help you.

Comment: The process is launched successfully, and I get WAIT_OBJECT_0 in return, but problem is it should wait for the child exe to finish.. which it is not doing....

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rob, it's not quite probable that WinAPI is wrong: if it says it's terminated, then it is.

Do you somehow follow the output of the child process? Is it possible that it failed early in its initialization, e.g. when trying to load DLLs for the wrong platform (32/64), getting some environment variables pointing to wrong location depending on the platform etc.?

Answer (score 0):

A little searching turned up this code for a `tcsh` implementation:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcsh/tcsh-60/tcsh/win32/fork.c

(Search for the second instance of "WaitForSingleObject")

It looks like they may have had the same problem that you did.  The WFSO is commented out and replaced by a set of shared events that the new and existing processes use to communicate.  Perhaps this is a common problem, or even a yet-to-be-fixed windows bug.